# How can I keep track of the links I shared?

Tags: sharing, links

Sometimes I share a link on twitter or google buzz and later something reminds me of it and I want to find it again, finding it is very difficult to search on my old tweets or Buzzes.

How can I keep better track of my shares independently of where I shared it from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sign up for a [bit.ly](http://bit.ly/) account and use it to shorten them. You can then look back at all of your previously shortened URIs.

If you want to add more data such as notes and possibly share that list, try a social bookmarking service such as [Delicious](http://delicious.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Friendfeed to capture all your content. Just add all your accounts and subscribe to the feed. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be creating a [Yahoo! Pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) with the feeds of all your online activities. You can filter all the urls then. It's pretty easy to create one but there are drawbacks:

1. Not everything you do online can be piped.
2. Pipes are not realtime: it takes several hours for them to be refreshed.

I would recommend you doing so only if you need to track th links you've *already* saved and switch to bit.ly as Simon Brown suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google Apps, you can use their **[Short Links](http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=5143210+6352879591152674960)** app if you don't like the other options...